# Poisson random variable. Average 1.2 per week, in 52 weeks, chance of 4 or more in a week?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose weekly number of fatal traffic accidents in a large city is a Poisson random variable with an average of 1.2 per week. During the next year ( 52 weeks), what is the probability that there is at least 1 week with four or more fatal accidents? ( assume independence from week to week. )

I have λ = np = (1.2)(52) = 62.4

I am not sure what to do from there. My thinking was 1 -  P(x=3) -  P(x=2) -  P(x=1) -  P(x=0) where x = the number of fatal accidents.

Comment: "x = the number of fatal accidents"... when? During one week? One year? And could you explain why you compute 1 - P(x=3) - P(x=2) - P(x=1) - P(x=0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prob that there is at least one week in the next 52 with fatal accidents is $1 - $ prob that there are no weeks of the 52 with at least 4 fatal accidents, or that all weeks in 52 have less than 4 fatal accidents.

The prob of a week having less than 4 fatal accidents is

$$P(N \lt 4) = e^{-\lambda} \left (1+\lambda+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}+\frac{\lambda^3}{6}\right)$$

The prob that all weeks are like this is $P(N \lt 4)^{52}$.  The prob that we seek is then

$$1-P(N \lt 4)^{52} = 1-e^{-52 \lambda} \left (1+\lambda+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}+\frac{\lambda^3}{6}\right)^{52}$$

For $\lambda=1.2$, I get this probability being about $0.832$.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the probability of having less than 4 fatal accidents per week as P(0) + P(1) + P(2) + P(3) = A

Since the weeks are independent, then the probability of having a year with no weeks of four or more accidents is A^52.

Then the probability of having at least 1 week with four or more fatal accidents is 1 - A^52